# JavaScript class - Override class function when specified?

Tags: javascript, function, class, overriding

I have a JavaScript class with some functions in it. One of those functions is an drop event which handles dragging and dropping files into a area. As soon the client dropped a file, a function named `onDrop` should be executed.

This `onDrop` function is located inside the class and should only be executed when the user drops a file. However, I need an possiblty to override the default class function `onDrop` with an own specified function from the class instance constructor. But, when there is no own specified function, use the default onDrop class function.

One of the two problems I have right now is that the default class function onDrop is executed immediately after creating a new instance of the class (which is wrong because this function should only be executed when the user draggend and dropped a file).

The second problem I have is when an user dropped a file, the onDrop function is never executed because an error in the console, which tells that the function onDrop is undefined.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here but at this time I don't know exactly what. Maybe someone can tell me more about this problem?

Let me explain this situation with the following code (and at the very bottom a codepen example)

```js
class myClass
{
 constructor(area, events)
 {
  this.events = Object.assign
  ({
     ondrop: this.onDrop()
  }, events);

    area.addEventListener('dragover', ev =>
  {
   ev.preventDefault();
  });

  area.addEventListener('drop', ev =>
  {
   ev.preventDefault();

   this.events.ondrop(ev);
  });
 }

 onDrop(ev)
 {
   alert('This is the onDrop function from the class itself');
 }
}


var area  = document.getElementById('file-upload');
var events = {
  // remove the comment tags to overwrite the default onDrop function from  the class
  //ondrop: function() {alert('This is the onDrop function from the instance')}
};
var instance = new myClass(area, events);
```

```css
body {
 font-family : sans-serif;
}
#file-drag {
 border        : 2px dashed #555;
 border-radius : 7px;
 color         : #555;
 cursor        : pointer;
 display       : block;
 font-weight   : bold;
 margin        : 1em 0;
 padding       : 3em;
 text-align    : center;
 transition    : background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}
#file-drag:hover {
 background : #ddd;
}
#file-drag:hover,
#file-drag.hover {
 border-color : #3070A5;
 border-style : solid;
 box-shadow   : inset 0 3px 4px #888;
 color        : #3070A5;
}
#file-upload-form {
 margin : auto; 
 width  : 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="file-upload">
 <label for="file-upload" id="file-drag">
  Drag a file into this box
 </label>
</div>
```

[Full Codes in Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQwxYM)

Comment: for both questions, it should be caused by `ondrop: this.onDrop()`. ondrop should be `function(){}` instead of one value returned by `this.onDrop()`.

Comment: `ondrop: this.onDrop` without parentheses should work.

Comment: Thank you both guys! The comment from @Don'tKnow did the trick. Sometimes a problem looks difficult but actually it isn't.Thanks again!